# How to override to_json in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, methods, overriding

---

## Update:

This issue was not properly explored. The real issue lies within `render :json`.

The first code paste in the original question will yield the expected result. However, there is still a caveat. See this example:

`render :json => current_user`

is **NOT** the same as

`render :json => current_user.to_json`

That is, `render :json` will not automatically call the `to_json` method associated with the User object. *In fact*, if `to_json` is being overridden on the `User` model, `render :json => @user` will generate the `ArgumentError` described below.

### summary

```
# works if User#to_json is not overridden
render :json => current_user

# If User#to_json is overridden, User requires explicit call
render :json => current_user.to_json
```

This all seems silly to me. This seems to be telling me that `render` is not actually calling `Model#to_json` when type `:json` is specified. Can someone explain what's really going on here?

Any genii that can help me with this can likely answer my other question: [How to build a JSON response by combining @foo.to_json(options) and @bars.to_json(options) in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572340/how-to-build-a-json-response-by-combining-foo-to-jsonoptions-and-bars-to-json)

---

## Original Question:

I've seen some other examples on SO, but I none do what I'm looking for.

I'm trying:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # this actually works! (see update summary above)
  def to_json
    super(:only => :username, :methods => [:foo, :bar])
  end

end
```

I'm getting `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` in

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/json/encoders/object.rb:4:in `to_json
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your example works in one of my models. Do any of the `username`, `foo` or `bar` methods expect arguments?

Comment: No, `username` is not a method and `foo` and `bar` do not require methods. I updated my question to show where the error is happening.

Comment: I'm running 1.8.7. You'll have to open up that file and see why it's passing an arg to a method that expects zero args.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You are getting `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` because `to_json` needs to be overridden with one parameter, the `options` hash.

```
def to_json(options)
  ...
end
```

---

**Longer explanation of `to_json`, `as_json`, and rendering:**

In ActiveSupport 2.3.3, `as_json` was added to address issues like the one you have encountered. The *creation* of the json should be separate from the *rendering* of the json.

Now, anytime `to_json` is called on an object, `as_json` is invoked to create the data structure, and then that hash is encoded as a JSON string using `ActiveSupport::json.encode`. This happens for all types: object, numeric, date, string, etc (see the ActiveSupport code).

ActiveRecord objects behave the same way. There is a default `as_json` implementation that creates a hash that includes all the model's attributes. **You should override `as_json` in your Model to create the JSON structure you want**. `as_json`, just like the old `to_json`, takes an option hash where you can specify attributes and methods to include declaratively.

```
def as_json(options)
  # this example ignores the user's options
  super(:only => [:email, :handle])
end
```

In your controller, `render :json => o` can accept a string or an object. **If it's a string, it's passed through as the response body, if it's an object, `to_json` is called, which triggers `as_json` as explained above.**

So, as long as your models are properly represented with `as_json` overrides (or not), your controller code to display one model should look like this:

```
format.json { render :json => @user }
```

The moral of the story is: **Avoid calling `to_json` directly, allow `render` to do that for you. If you need to tweak the JSON output, call `as_json`.**

```
format.json { render :json => 
    @user.as_json(:only => [:username], :methods => [:avatar]) }
```

Comment: @Jonathan Julian, this is a very helpful explanation of `as_json`. As you can see in the ActiveRecord::Serialization docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001874), there is very little (no) documentation for this. I will give this a try :)

Comment: @Jonathan Julian, if I could up-vote this 10 times, I would. Where the heck are the `as_json` docs! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 71):

If you're having issues with this in Rails 3, override `serializable_hash` instead of `as_json`. This will get your XML formatting for free too :)

Comment: Does anyone know of any good write-ups about the method `serializable_hash`?  When I use it, it changes my subsequent xml output from wrapping the object with its name (e.g. "quote" for a quote object") to instead always wrap it with "<hash>".

Comment: @TylerCollier it should be same options as `to_xml`

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I'm using ruby2/rails4 and as_json wasn't working with nested objects, overridden method wasn't called in 'include', with serializable_hash it works!

Comment: See https://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json for an explanation of why serializable_hash should be overriden instead.

Answer (score 37):

For people who don't want to ignore users options but also add their's:

```
def as_json(options)
  # this example DOES NOT ignore the user's options
  super({:only => [:email, :handle]}.merge(options))
end
```

Hope this helps anyone :)

Comment: This is the way I do it, except I default the `options` hash with `= {}` so it's not required when calling

Answer (score 5):

Override not to_json, but as_json.
And from as_json call what you want:

Try this:

```
def as_json 
 { :username => username, :foo => foo, :bar => bar }
end
```

Comment: Isn't `as_json` just for ActiveResource?

Comment: Apparently ActiveRecord::Serialization has as_json http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html

Comment: @glebm, I tried this and I'm getting the same result. I updated my question to show you.

Comment: @glebm, I'm still getting the exact same error. Even when I do `render :json => current_user` I get the expected default result (all attributes for `User` model in JSON format). When I add the `as_json` method to my `User` model and try the same thing, I get the error :(

Comment: @glebm, thank you. I know I was doing something wrong. It might be worth checking out the updated question.

Comment: Basically, starting from 2.3.2 you are supposed to call `as_json` instead of `to_json` (i.e. `render :json => <...>.as_json`)