# How to build a JSON response made up of multiple models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

### First, the desired result

I have `User` and `Item` models. I'd like to build a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
  "user":
    {"username":"Bob!","foo":"whatever","bar":"hello!"},

  "items": [
    {"id":1, "name":"one", "zim":"planet", "gir":"earth"},
    {"id":2, "name":"two", "zim":"planet", "gir":"mars"}
  ]
}
```

However, my `User` and `Item` model have more attributes than just those. I found a way to get this to work, but **beware**, it's not pretty... Please help...

#### Update

The next section contains the original question. The last section shows the new solution.

---

### My hacks

#### home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def observe
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :json => Observation.new(current_user, @items).to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

#### observation.rb

```
# NOTE: this is not a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base
# this class just serves as a container to aggregate all "observable" objects
class Observation
  attr_accessor :user, :items

  def initialize(user, items)
    self.user = user
    self.items = items
  end

  # The JSON needs to be decoded before it's sent to the `to_json` method in the home_controller otherwise the JSON will be escaped...
  # What a mess!
  def to_json
    {
      :user => ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(user.to_json(:only => :username, :methods => [:foo, :bar])),
      :items => ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(auctions.to_json(:only => [:id, :name], :methods => [:zim, :gir]))
    }
  end
end
```

---

## Look Ma! No more hacks!

### Override `as_json` instead

The [ActiveRecord::Serialization#as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001874) docs are pretty sparse. Here's the brief:

```
as_json(options = nil) 
  [show source]
```

For more information on `to_json` vs `as_json`, see the accepted answer for [Overriding to_json in Rails 2.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5)

### The code sans hacks

#### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json(options)
    options = { :only => [:username], :methods => [:foo, :bar] }.merge(options)
    super(options)
  end

end
```

#### item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json(options)
    options = { :only => [:id, name], :methods => [:zim, :gir] }.merge(options)
    super(options)
  end

end
```

#### home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def observe
    @items = Items.find(...)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        render :json => {
          :user => current_user || {},
          :items => @items
        }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDITED** to use `as_json` instead of `to_json`. See [How to override to_json in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5/2574900) for a detailed explanation. I think this is the best answer.

You can render the JSON you want in the controller without the need for the helper model.

```
def observe
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      render :json => {
        :user => current_user.as_json(:only => [:username], :methods => [:foo, :bar]),
        :items => @items.collect{ |i| i.as_json(:only => [:id, :name], :methods => [:zim, :gir]) }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Make sure `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json` is set to false or else you'll get a 'user' attribute inside of 'user'. Unfortunately, it looks like Arrays do not pass `options` down to each element, so the `collect` is necessary.

Comment: The hash syntax you're using is only from 1.9 and may confuse anyone who's not familiar with it. May I suggest changing it to be the standard `"user" => current` that we all "know and love"?

Comment: @Jonathan Julian, `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json` is set to `false` and this is doing exactly what I *expected*, but not exactly what I *hoped* for. The internal `to_json` calls are getting escaped by `render :json`. For example, instead of `{"user": {"username": "Bob!"}}` I am getting `{"user": "{\"username\": \"Bob!\"}"}` :(

Comment: @ryan fixed hash syntax to be ruby 1.8 style

Comment: @Ryan Bigg, it's actually a typo. (And a syntax error, ever for Ruby 1.9). He means `{:user => current_user...}`

Comment: @smotchkkisss You can always `render :json => {}` and just build up that hash by hand *without* calling to_json on the models. Or use `decode` as you've already found. Either way, there's no need for a separate model.

Comment: @Jonathan Julian, thanks for giving this a shot. You might want to make a "does not work" note somewhere in your answer so people don't chase down the same dead end I did. +1 for effort

Comment: @Ryan Bigg, I looked into this new syntax a bit. `{a: "foo"}` is valid, `{'a': "foo"}` is not. Like you, I still prefer the `{:foo => "bar"}` notation :)

Comment: @Jonathan Julian, thanks again. I updated the original question to show the application of the new `as_json` override as well. This make me very happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone is looking for an alternative solution for this, this is how I solved this in Rails 4.2:

```
def observe
  @item = some_item
  @user = some_user

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      serialized_item = ItemSerializer.new(@item).attributes
      serialized_user = UserSerializer.new(@user).attributes
      render :json => {
        :item => serialized_item, 
        :user => serialized_user
      }
    end
  end
end
```

This returns the serialized version of both objects as JSON, accessible via `response.user` and `response.item`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of new Gems for building JSON now, for this case the most suitable I have found is Jsonify:

https://github.com/bsiggelkow/jsonify
https://github.com/bsiggelkow/jsonify-rails

This allows you to build up the mix of attributes and arrays from your models.

Answer (score -1):

**Working answer #2** To avoid the issue of your json being "escaped", build up the data structure by hand, then call to_json on it *once*. It can get a little wordy, but you can do it all in the controller, or abstract it out to the individual models as `to_hash` or something.

```
def observe
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      render :json => {
        :user => {:username => current_user.username, :foo => current_user.foo, :bar => current_user.bar},
        :items => @items.collect{ |i| {:id => i.id, :name => i.name, :zim => i.zim, :gir => i.gir} }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: See why I had my "Override `to_json` in Rails 2.3.5" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5) question before? ;)

Comment: To solve both your problems, create a `to_hash` in each of your models and build them yourself. Trade off a bit of code for a couple headaches.

Comment: please update `@items.each` to read `@items.collect`. `Array#each` returns the original `@items` array. This is only mildly cleaner than what I had before, but it still seems like I should be able to tap into the `as_json` or `to_json` methods somehow; I mean, that's what they're for. It's very possible that many more objects will be appearing in the "Observation" hash, so doing all this extra work for each one seems like it could be a headache of its own. If a more suitable answer doesn't appear in a couple days, I'll mark this as accepted. Thanks again :)