# How do I combine two methods into one json formatted variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm storing JSON formatted data into a `var adds` with the following methods:

```
var adds = <%= raw @add.to_a.to_json %>;

var adds = <%= raw @add.nearbys(1).to_json %>;
```

The first line of code stores the location of an individual in JSON format, the second line of code searches for that person's neighbors, within a 1 mile range. **How do I combine both** of these lines of code and store the data in JSON format in the `var adds` variable?

If you are interested in source, its [here](http://github.com/fogonthedowns/Yardsign). The location is layout/adds.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's so important to have both pieces of data in one adds variable (can you simply do `var adds` and then`var addNearbys`?), but

```
var adds = {
    all: <%= raw @add.to_a.to_json %>,
    nearbys: <%= raw @add.nearbys(1).to_json %>
};
```

would get you all the data in one variable, in JSON.

Alternatively, you could do

```
var adds = <%= {:all => @add.to_a, :nearby => @add.nearbys(1)}.to_json %>
```

but that takes more processing because you'd be initializing a Hash.

Answer (score 0):

This was recently a huge issue for me and the solution is actually very elegant.

**Note:** be wary of the `to_json` solutions for aggregating JSON strings.

[See my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572340/how-to-build-a-json-response-by-combining-foo-to-jsonoptions-and-bars-to-json)