# Add virtual attribute to json output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Let's say I have an app that handles a TODO list. The list has finished and unfinished items. Now I want to add two virtual attributes to the list object; the count of finished and unfinished items in the list. I also need these to be displayed in the json output.

I have two methods in my model which fetches the unfinished/finished items:

```
def unfinished_items 
  self.items.where("status = ?", false) 
end 

def finished_items 
  self.items.where("status = ?", true) 
end
```

So, how can I get the count of these two methods in my json output?

I'm using Rails 3.1

Comment: i have not tried this: maybe all you have to do is add an attr_reader :finished_items ?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The serialization of objects in Rails has two steps:

- First, `as_json` is called to convert the object to a simplified Hash.
- Then, `to_json` is called on the `as_json` return value to get the final JSON string.

You generally want to leave `to_json` alone so all you need to do is add [your own `as_json` implementation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) sort of like this:

```
def as_json(options = { })
  # just in case someone says as_json(nil) and bypasses
  # our default...
  super((options || { }).merge({
    :methods => [:finished_items, :unfinished_items]
  }))
end
```

You could also do it like this:

```
def as_json(options = { })
  h = super(options)
  h[:finished]   = finished_items
  h[:unfinished] = unfinished_items
  h
end
```

if you wanted to use different names for the method-backed values.

If you care about XML and JSON, have a look at [`serializable_hash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html).

Comment: I got this error with the top one:
undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass

So I replaced `options.merge` with `(options||{}).merge`.

Comment: @Turadg: The first one should work due to the default `options = { }` unless someone is passing an explicit `nil` in somewhere, I'll patch in the extra paranoia just to be safe. Sorry, your comment got lost in the daily chaos so I'm a bit late getting back to you.

Answer (score 38):

With Rails 4, you can do the following -

```
render json: @my_object.to_json(:methods => [:finished_items, :unfinished_items])
```

Hope this helps somebody who is on the later / latest version

Answer (score 19):

Another way to do this is add this to your model:

```
def attributes
  super.merge({'unfinished' => unfinished_items, 'finished' => finished_items})
end
```

This would also automatically work for xml serialization. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html
Be aware though, you might want use strings for the keys, since the method can not deal with symbols when sorting the keys in rails 3. But it is not sorted in rails 4, so there shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Comment: This is also a good way to make sure the virtual attribute is included when rendering an associated object and using `include:` (I've used this to solve problems with using the attr_encrypted gem)

Answer (score 3):

just close all of your data **into one hash**, like

`render json: {items: items, finished: finished, unfinished: unfinished}`

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd provide this answer for anyone like myself, who was trying to integrate this into an existing **as_json** block:

```
  def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:id, :longitude, :latitude],
          :include => {
            :users => {:only => [:id]}
          }
    ).merge({:premium => premium?})
```

Just tack `.merge({})` on to the end of your `super()`

Answer (score 1):

This will do, without having to do some ugly overridings. If you got a model `List` for example, you can put this in your controller:

```
  render json: list.attributes.merge({
                                       finished_items: list.finished_items,
                                       unfinished_items: list.unfinished_items
                                     })
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Aswin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419959/aswin-ramakrishnan) listed above, `:methods` will enable you to return a specific model's method/function as a json attribute, in case you have complex assosiations this will do the trick since it will add functions to the existing model/assossiations :D it will work like a charm if you dont want to redefine `as_json`

Check this code, and please notice how i'm using `:methods` as well as `:include` [N+Query is not even an option ;)]

`render json: @YOUR_MODEL.to_json(:methods => [:method_1, :method_2], :include => [:company, :surveys, :customer => {:include => [:user]}])`

Overwritting `as_json` function will be way harder in this scenario (specially because you have to add the `:include` assossiations manually :/

`def as_json(options = { })
end`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render an array of objects with their virtual attributes, you can use

```
render json: many_users.as_json(methods: [:first_name, :last_name])
```

where `first_name` and `last_name` are virtual attributes defined on your model