# Rails Generate Nested JSON

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have two objects, an @article and a @profile. Article is a model and @profile is a Struct. I'd like to end up with some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "article": {
        "title": "this is a title",
        "author": "Author McAuthor",
        "profile": {
            "first_name": "Bobby",
            "last_name": "Fisher"
        }
    }
}
```

As of now, I can just manually create this by doing something like:

```
@json = { article: { title: @article.title, author: @article.author, profile: { first_name: @profile.first_name, last_name: @profile.last_name } }}
```

I feel like building the json object this way is sorta crude, also, every time I change the author model, I might have to change this code. It would be great if I could find an easier way to build these json objects without having to do so manually... Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Build whatever ruby structure you like (consisting of arrays and hashes), and then use .to_json on it. But then, I just found at least one person does not like that - http://blog.gomiso.com/2011/05/16/if-youre-using-to_json-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: you mind being a bit more specific?

Comment: If you have a Ruby variable, a has for example, you can call variable.to_json and get the json string as a result. Rails adds a to_josn method on Object (all it does is call ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(self, options)). See http://api.rubyonrails.org/, enter to_json in the search box.

Comment: i am aware of those methods. i am trying to nest one object inside another object in json without building the strings manually, then add new attributes to where i'm building the json string every time the objects update.

Comment: It's better to override `as_json`: http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/

Comment: Well, just DO it - what's the problem? Manipulate the Ruby object as much as you like! Not a JSON issue - only at THE END you call some procedure that "stringifies" it into JSON text. You are confused - like too many! - about what JSON is. You have no JSON issue at all. You have an issue with very normal ruby objects or hashes. It can be represented as text in JSON format, but that is not your problem.

Comment: Do you ever have more than one of anything?

Comment: @MarkThomas these will always be 1 to 1, so for every article, there should be a nested profile, this just makes things much easier for the iOS developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to shioyama's correct answer, you can use [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to craft your JSON objects, similar to how ERB works for views.

For example, you would create a 'view', say, `index.rabl`.  It would look like:

```
collection @articles
attributes :author, :title
child(:profile) { attributes :first_name, :last_name }
```

Comment: +1 This is what I was going to say. The `rabl` gem builds your JSON API using a standard Rails view. This gives you the ultimate flexibility and avoids the tendency to couple your model schema to your API.

Comment: @Sean Hill curious, if i wanted to create that child(:profile) but then create a custom attribute called "profile_views" how would i do that?

Comment: Then you would do `child(:profile) { attributes :first_name, :last_name; node(:profile_views) { |profile| profile.profile_views } }`, assuming that `profile_views` is a method on the profile instance.

Answer (score 2):

Rails serializes objects in two steps, first by calling `as_json` to create the object to be serialized, then by calling `to_json` to actually create the JSON string.

Generally, if you want to customize how your models are represented in JSON, it's best to override `as_json`. Assuming your profile struct is a virtual attribute (i.e. defined with `attr_accessor`, not saved in the db), you could do this in your `Article` model:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super((options || {}).merge({
    :methods => :profile
  }))
end
```

Hope that helps. See also:

- [`as_json` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)
- [Add virtual attribute to json output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892044/add-virtual-attribute-to-json-output)

Comment: Updated my answer to pass through any options to `super`.

Comment: +1 thanks @shioyama. i will look into that. \@profile is not a virtual attribute, but perhaps it should be?

Comment: so this code is saying that we are going to merge the result of the method profile into the article json?

Comment: It says we are going to merge the key/value pair `:methods => :profile` into whatever options are passed in to `as_json` when it is caled. The `:methods` option is used to declare any method return values you want to include in your JSON. So if you have a method `profile` which returns an object, then it will be included and converted to JSON using `to_json`. Hope that makes sense.