# Rails transient attribute is not rendered to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I´m trying to send a transient attribute (that I don´t want to persist in database) in json response. I send all model attributes but this transient one. I´m trying to overwrite the to_json method in order to add this attribute. I have read some entries related to this, but it´s not working for me. I´m missing something.

My model:

```
class Boat < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :price

  def to_json(options = {})
    options[:methods] = :price;
    super(options)
  end

  belongs_to :boat_model
  belongs_to :port

end
```

My controller:

```
   @boats = Boat.find_by_sql(["SELECT * 
                                FROM boats b, ports p
                                WHERE p.name = ? 
                                AND b.port_id = p.id", port])
    @boats[0].price = 89
    @boats[1].price = 130

    puts 'price:' + @boats[0].price.to_s

    puts @boats.inspect
    render :json => @boats
```

Neither the inspect nor the json response sends or displays the price attribute.

Comment: I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892044/add-virtual-attribute-to-json-output

Comment: options[:methods] = price   (remove the symbol specifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the post I attach in the comments above.

[Add virtual attribute to json output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892044/add-virtual-attribute-to-json-output)