# Rails include additional attribute in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
def index
    @project = Project.where(id: params[:id]).first

    email = {:email => 'test@mail.com'}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end
end
```

When run application, I will get the result like this:

```
{"project":{"id":1, "name" => "project name"}}
```

Now I want `email` be included as an additional attribute in `@project` json.

```
{"project":{"id":1, "name" => "project name", "email" => "test@mail.com"}}
```

Note that `email` is not a table field.

How to do that?

*Sorry for my bad English*

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892044/add-virtual-attribute-to-json-output

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible the way you describe, at least without making a new form field, or without users who want to edit their own forms with their browser tools.

What I think you mean is that you already have an email associated with project, and you want to save that to the DB with the rest of the information. If that's the case then you can handle that in the controller (the create action) or in the model. I prefer controller since you're explicitly pulling things from the database there anyways.

You can do something like `@project.email = #{some logic that goes and gets it here}` right before the `@project.save`.

Also don't use a hidden field to get the email into the JSON if it's important that people cannot fake which email is associated with which project.