# How to modify to_json method and add a dynamic property to it - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

so i have this controller and i want to add a dynamic attribute along with the other data in the @events instance variable

i have search and tried things like **@events.attributes.merge(appointment: true)**

**appointment = true** is what i want to add to the events object.

```
def find
params = event_params

current_user = 2
@events = Event.where('date LIKE ?',"%#{params[:month]}%")

def @events.as_json(options = { })
    h = super(options)
    h[:appointments]   = false # Or combine with above h[:appointments] = self.appointments?
    h
end

respond_to do |format|
  if current_user == 1

    if @events

      format.json {
        render json: @events.to_json
      }
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  else

    format.json {
      render json: @events.to_json
    }
  end
end
```

end

**ajax code here**

```
function retrieve(date_partial) {

    var jsondata = {
      events: {
        month: date_partial,
      }
    }

    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      url: "/events/find",
      data: jsondata,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var day = data[i].date.substring(0, 2);
          $("td[data-day='" + day + "']").addClass('added');
        }

      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        alert("The error code is: " + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
```

so how can i add that property?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a method/instance variable to the object in memory ? Or you want to also persist this new attribute in the database ?

Comment: I just want to add that method and render it to the view without storing it anywhere in db so i have access to that method value on success of ajax request.

Comment: Alright, for JSON/AJAX this become more problematic, because you also have to override the `to_json` to include the new field, not just the object in memory (ie: explicitely tell the serializer to include your new field). Also, you should edit the question title to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could work ? But then maybe the JSON output isn't what you expected ?

```
format.json { render :json => {events: @events, appointments: true} }
```

Comment: Sorry it took some time for a simple line of code. Instead of posting an answer for a different question, I ended up editing someone else's answer, and when I noticed, then I had to figure how to rollback my mistake ^^". That'll teach me to close tabs :

Answer (score 2):

Because this property is view oriented, the model should not know about it. A better way to do this, is to use a decorator, which will allow you to add what ever attributes you want in the manner you want, without polluting the model.
you can create a PORO object
like this one

```
# this is by no means a complete implementation, but just for you
# to get the idea
class EventDecorator
  # use ( delegate :event_attribute, to: :event ) to delegate 
  # all the event attributes and to be able to access them
  # as if they were declared on the decorator itself
  attr_reader :event
  attr_accessor :appointment
  def initialize(event)
    @event = event
    @appointment = false
  end

  def to_json
     event.attributes.merge(appointment: appointment).to_json
  end
end
```

a better way is to use the [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) gem. You can find a good explanation in this railscat, [#286 Draper](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper)

Comment: Sounds nice, but you should also show how to use it within the OP's context.

Comment: damn i have no idea how to implement that ;o - EDIT: What Cyril said ;p

Comment: take a look here to understand what a decorator is https://github.com/drapergem/draper#why-use-a-decorator  and how to use it.

Comment: Ok, take some time reading the draper readme, it worth learning it. It's not very complex, and once you understand it, your code will be much more organized and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do that I can think of: adding an instance variable or a custom method (or something hybrid)

EDIT : Forget what I said about creating an instance variable out of nowhere ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552991/2832282))^^"

**Method**

```
@events.define_singleton_method(:appointments?){true/false}
@events.appointments? # => true/false
```

EDIT 2 : AJAX/JSON override

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6892207/2832282)

```
def @events.as_json(options = { })
    h = super(options)
    h[:appointments]   = true/false # Or combine with above h[:appointments] = self.appointments?
    h
end
```

Comment: i've tried your first method (instance variable) and i get this for anyname (`appointment' is not allowed as an instance variable name)

Comment: with your second method, i get no errors, but i cant see it in the returned data of the ajax request...

Comment: The problem becomes harder if you actually also want to serialize/AJAX this. Can you edit your question to add the relevant view code ?

Comment: i've added it now! :)

Comment: hmm i saw your new code but i want to pass the events.appointment value to the view,through the ajax success callback i guess what you give me is for the rails controller?

Comment: I added stuff for the serialization part. Untested though.

Comment: so i leave it as it is, i just add this block of code outside of the def find [...] end?

Comment: Nono, inside your controller method, it should work. `def @events.as_json` should behave the same as `@events.define_singleton_method(:as_json){...}`

Comment: i see, i have edited my post above to check if everything seems ok, and i get this error, typeError in EventsController#find

no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm sorry ! Your @events variable is an array. My method is only working for a hash. I will actually add another answer which will fit better your problem.

Comment: oh thats right its an array of objects., i am waiting for it :D