# Ruby, objects does not keep their values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model `Shop` which has this kind of method:

```
def distance(dist)
  @distance = dist
end
```

Then in `as_json` method I do something like this:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  result = super(include: [:distance])
  if @distance.nil?
    @distance = -1
  end
  result[:distance] = @distance
  result
end
```

Then somwhere else I assign distance each `Shop` some kind of value:

```
shops.each do |shop|
  distance = 123123
  shop.distance distance / 1000
end
puts shops.to_json
```

When I call `puts shops.to_json` method it shows me JSON Array of my Shops where each `distance` equals to `-1`.

This distance value keeps inside cycle but not outside when I access to array.

Why this is happening? It does not keep value that I sent.

---

**Update**

I have solved it by doing using additional array:

```
arr = []
shops.each do |shop|
   distance = HelperModule.distance_in_meters loc, shop.location
   shop.distance distance / 1000
   arr << shop
end
shops = arr
puts shops.to_json
```

However, this solution is not so good. It just creates new array and reassigns it to first one.

Comment: after assigning distance to shop in `shop.distance distance / 1000` don't you need to save the shop model?

Comment: I tryed this on my own, and for each shop I get a Hash of two elements, { "distance" => 12, :distance => 12 }

Comment: `distance` is not field in database. It is calculated variable that will be added to json structure. The main problem is that I have similar another method that stores boolean value that works and this is not,

Comment: I guess there is another `distance` method defined on a shop: directly in the code somewhere, via `attr_accessor` or `attr_reader` or because there exists a similar named database column. Try and add `raise dist` to your `distance` method and check if it is actually called.

Comment: Yes I have checked. I have added `puts @distance` in `distance` method and it is called and assigned this value. However, in `as_json` method it is already `nil`. I don't know why.

Comment: Indeed, this should have worked. Would you make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) out of this?

Comment: Please write the update into it's own answer and remove it from the question.

Comment: @Tobias I don't consider it as solution. It is wrong, but it works somehow. Is there another elegant solution for this?

Comment: What is `shops` ? It sounds like it is refetching objects from the db

Comment: @FrederickCheung. It is array of `Shop` objects which was fetched from database and filtered before I call this loop

Comment: Could you add the complete classes. It is a little bit hard to understand what is in which scope.

Comment: @QQQ definitely an array and not a scope / relation?

Comment: @QQQ Why don't you use an `attribute_writer` instead of the method `distance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, as I mentioned in my updated question, if I assign values to new array and then reassign it to original one:

```
arr = []
shops.each do |shop|
  distance = HelperModule.distance_in_meters loc, shop.location
  shop.distance distance / 1000
  arr << shop
end
shops = arr
puts shops.to_json
```

The second method that worked is that i used this before calling loop:

```
shops = shops.to_a
```

What I have found it is that this array, which was fetched from database, is not an array at all. It is some kind of enumerable criteria, which can work as an array, but has some kind of differencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the @ from distance

Comment: How I will assign its value inside `as_json` method?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892044/add-virtual-attribute-to-json-output

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanation is MUCH more useful for the readers of the StackOverflow knowledge base :)