# Active Record to_json\as_json on Array of Models

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, activesupport

First off, I am not using Rails. I am using Sinatra for this project with Active Record.

I want to be able to override either to_json or as_json on my Model class and have it define some 'default' options. For example I have the following:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_json(options = {})
    if options.empty?
      super :only => [:id, :name]
    else
      super options
    end
  end
end
```

where Vendor has more attributes than just id and name. In my route I have something like the following:

```
@vendors = Vendor.where({})
@vendors.to_json
```

Here `@vendors` is an Array vendor objects (obviously). The returned json is, however, not invoking my `to_json` method and is returning all of the models attributes.

I don't really have the option of modifying the route because I am actually using a modified sinatra-rest gem (http://github.com/mikeycgto/sinatra-rest).

Any ideas on how to achieve this functionality? I could do something like the following in my sinatra-rest gem but this seems silly:

```
@PLURAL.collect! { |obj| obj.to_json }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try overriding serializable_hash intead:

```
def serializable_hash(options = nil)
  { :id => id, :name => name }
end
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5).

Comment: exactly what I need. I like the fact that I could also add in properties that aren't attributes as well. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

If you override as_json instead of to_json, each element in the array will format with as_json before the array is converted to JSON

I'm using the following to only expose only accessible attributes:

```
def as_json(options = {})
    options[:only] ||= self.class.accessible_attributes.to_a
    super(options)
end
```