# How to customize the to_json method in rails3?

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to convert an array of Place objects to json, I've been doing it like this:

```
var places = <%= @places.to_json.html_safe %>;
```

The only problem is that every place in the @places array has an associated tag list that doesn't get included. I'm using the acts_as_taggable_on gem to handle tags, so to get the tag list for a place I need to say place.tag_list.

What do I have to do to get the tag_list included for each place in the javascript array? I think I'll need to write my own to_json method but I don't know how.

EDIT

It turns out that this is easier than I realized. I was able to say this:

```
var places = <%= @places.to_json(:include => :tags).html_safe %>
```

The only problem is that this includes more information about each tag than I really need. Every tag has an id and name, what I really want is just a list with tag names in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `to_json` method also accepts an argument called `methods`.  This argument allows you to specify methods that should be called and included in the json representation of the object.  Since you mentioned that you have a method called `tag_list`, you can do this:

```
var places = <%= @places.to_json(:methods => :tag_list).html_safe %>
```

If, for some reason, you don't have a method to produce tag names, but each tag has a method to give you its name, you could add a method inside your `Place` model to produce a list of tag names like so:

```
def tag_names
    tags.collect do |tag|
        tag.name
    end
end
```

Then you could get your places json with `tag_names` like this:

```
place_json = @places.to_json(:methods => :tag_names)
```

This technique will work for any computed attributes you'd like to add to a model's json representation.

Comment: +1 - nice! I can think of a million places I will use this :)

Answer (score 2):

Within your Place class, you can override to_json.  In Rails 3, you should override as_json instead:

```
def as_json (options={})
  # add whatever fields you need here
end
```

Then change your code to:

```
var places = <%= @places.as_json.html_safe %>;
```

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand what the method would look like though. I don't understand how to include each places tag_list.

Comment: agreed, Benson's answer is awesome

Answer (score 1):

Benson's answer will not work if you are calling

```
render :json => @places
```

in the PlacesController. You will need to add the following code in the Place model.

```
# this method is called on a single instance
def to_json(options={})
  options[:methods] ||= []
  options[:methods] << :tag_names
  super(options)
end

# this method is called for each instance in an Array to avoid circular references.
def as_json(options={})
  options[:methods] ||= []
  options[:methods] << :tag_names
  super(options)
end
```

Hope that helps someone else. I had to look through the source code to figure out why `Array.to_json` is not the same as `Array.each { |a| a.to_json }`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out this post if you are doing more complex JSON.

[How to override to_json in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5)

See those two posts as well:

http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2011/03/25/recursive-custom-to_json-in-ruby-for-arrays-of-objects-or-nested-objects/

http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/