# How to change values overriding the 'to_json' method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, overriding

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to override the `to_json` method.

At this time I use the following code in order to avoid to export important information.

```
  def to_json
    super(
      :except => [
        :password
      ]
    )
  end
```

**If I want change a value using that method, how I can do?**

For example, I would like to capitalize the user name

```
:name => name.capitalize
```

on retrieving this

```
@user.to_json
```

Comment: Similar problem here, could be helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703509/how-to-customize-the-to-json-method-in-rails3

Answer (score 12):

If you want to `render :json => @user` in the controller for Rails 3, you can override `as_json` in the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(options={})
    result = super({ :except => :password }.merge(options))
    result["user"]["name"] = name.capitalize
    result
  end
end
```

Here's a good post about the [differences between to_json and as_json](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/).

Comment: FWIW, when calling `user.to_json`, in Rails 3.1.3, I was seeing the `as_json` receiving `nil` for the options argument, so I added `options ||= {}` as the first line of my custom `as_json` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:methods` option to `to_json`.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

Comment: I need a `def to_json ...` (in my model) and not `konata.to_json(:methods => :permalink)` (in controller or anywhere else)

Comment: Oh, so you want to override the default to_json? That is fine, I think.

Comment: I tryed multiple tests, but I was getting always errors. Please, can you make me a working example?

Comment: I think the problem linked here by Iashleigh is useful.  If you are using Rails3, you should probably override as_json, as mentioned there.