# include 2nd level in to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm using this code to convert a model to json. If i try to use an include 2nd level like this:

```
p = Product.includes({ :variants => { :stocks => :size } }).where(:id => params[:id]).first
render :json => p.variants.to_json(:include => { :stocks => { :include => :size } })
```

I receive this error:

```
undefined method `macro' for nil:NilClass
```

How I can solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render :json => p.variants.map { |v| v.as_json(:include => {:stocks => {:include => :size}}) }
```

Info about `Object#as_json`/`to_json` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5).