# additional attributes in both JSON and XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, xml-serialization, jsonserializer

I am currently trying to incorporate attributes in the API of my Rails app. The use case is simple. I have a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email
end
```

I have another model, basically linking the users to an Event:

```
class UserEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

I want to be able to list all users related to an event using the UserEvent model through an API accessible as JSON or XML, and I would like the email of my UserEvent to appear in both XML and JSON dump.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162444/want-consistent-behavior-in-to-xml-and-to-json) suggests that I can just override serialiable_hash, well this appears to work only for JSON, as it looks like serializable_hash is not used by to_xml

Another approach I have investigated was to override the attributes method in my class:

```
class UserEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
   def attributes
    @attributes = @attributes.merge "email" => self.email
    @attributes
  end
end
```

This works well for JSON, but throws an error when trying the XML version:

```
undefined method `xmlschema' for "2011-07-12 07:20:50.834587":String
```

This string turns out to be the "created_at" attribute of my object. So it looks like I am doing something wrong on the hash I am manipulating here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add additional nested data into API responses using `include`. Here's an example:

`respond_with(@user, :include => :user_event )`

You should also add the reverse association in `User`:

`has_many :user_events`

You can pass in an array to `:include` for multiple models. It'll serialize and nest them in the response appropriately.

Comment: What I did not mention in my question is that I want to do this in the model because it must be taken into account in several controllers.

Comment: No problem! Just override `as_json` in your model. This method gets called every time a model object is serialized to JSON, so it'll get used everywhere.

     `def as_json(options = {})
            super options.merge(include: :user_event)
        end`