# Rails 3: Rendering certain attributes of an array of objects in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm trying to pass some data to javascript in my view. I only want certain attributes of the objects in the array.

The json gem doesn't appear to support the `:only` option. I tried to use ActiveSupport::JSON

```
<script>
test1=<%=raw ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(@sectionDatas.values, :only => [ :left, :width ])%>;
</script>
```

but that ignores the `:only` and prints the whole object.

Then I thought I would be clever and take the `render` method from the controller:

```
test2=<%=raw render :json => @sections.as_json(:only => [:left, :width])%>
```

but I get Nil:Nilclass errors.

I also tried to put this in my model and run to_json:

```
include ActiveModel::Serialization::JSON

def attributes
  @attributes ||= {'left' => 0, 'width'=>0}
end
```

Again, this ignores the attributes method and serializes the whole object.

Surely this must be simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the columns you don't need when you get objects from the db with `select`.

```
Item.find( :all, :select => 'DISTINCT fieldname' )
```

Of course, this is not the Rails3 way. Here that is:

```
Model.select(attribute)
```

## Update

If you want to have the original array of objects and json but the json with filtered attributes you will need to override to_json:

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5) explains how to do that:

[How to override to_json in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5)

Comment: Won't that cause an extra query to the database for data I already have?

Comment: I was assuming that you would replace the it with the code I suggested.

Comment: Yep but I need the full object too, don't see the use in doing an extra query for data I already have. Also I can't find any docs on .select, is it part of ActiveRecord?

Comment: you need to override to_json in your model then. Check the update.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the objects in the array are instances of `ActiveRecord::Base` or include `ActiveModel::Serialization::JSON`:

```
test2=<%=raw @sections.to_json(:only => [:left, :width]) %>
```