# retrieve user object less specified attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This might be extremely simple: I have a controller that returns a user object when passed a param.

```
def show
  if params[:mob]
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_with([user.establishments,
                user])
```

this returns the entire user object. That is a problem because on the user object is the encrypted password, hash, and various other pieces of data I do not want to expose.

What would be the proper syntax to have it return the user object less some specified attributes? I am looking for a solution where I do not have manually create a new hash out of the user attributes I want to expose because it would be must simpler to just say, "give me user without x and y" than "give me a hash of user.a, user.b, user.c, ... user.n"

thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a problem for when you return the data in xml or json.

You can get around this by doing something like this to exclude certain fields.

```
obj.to_xml(:except => [ :created_at, :updated_at ])
```

or you can override the to_xml function in the model to always exclude values.

Comment: yes exactly the case. this is the method I am looking for. but how to apply it without calling .to_json first? My controller is already responding with format json so calling to_json is redundant. Can I call the :except block directly on the user? How? thx!

Comment: you could override it in your model to always do that, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5

Answer (score 1):

Here's a another suggestion.

Create a new method that "sanitizes" the user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def strip_sensitive_data!
    [:password, :ssn, :birth_date].each { |m| send("#{m}=", nil) }
  end
  ...
end

user = User.find(params[:id]).strip_sensitive_data!
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a instance method on the User object which would return a new User object with the required attributes?