# Rails show method not returning associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, rest

I have an object which has a reference to another using the :through approach.

When I perform the "show" method, the objects details are returned but not its associated objects. I've tried including the objects in the find like so:

```
@recipe = Recipe.includes(:quantities).find(params[:id])
```

but to no avail.

When I debug the code and do

```
@recipes.quantities
```

then I'm returned the correct set but the set isn't returned in the json by default. How I can make it so?

Comment: To clarify your question:  What you are asking is "When I have an object with associations, how do I retrieve the object and all of its relationships in such a way that I can serialize the object and its associations to json?"  Is that correct?

Comment: More or less yes. The quantities associations are not sent back down in the json with @recipe

Comment: I think that's the expected behavior.  When you serialize an object to json, it serializes that object, not related objects.  You can still serialize an object and it's relationships, but I think you'll need to do this by explicitly serializing the relationship objects.

Comment: Yep I can pass down the associated objects individually but it'd be nice to just send down the one single object complete with associated objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `show` method do something like this

```
def show
  @recipe = Recipe.includes(:quantities).find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.json { render json: @recipe.as_json(:include => :quantities)}
   end
 end
```

This is actually kinda hidden in the Rails source, but `as_json` makes more sense to use as per an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5/2574900).

Documentation: [ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)