# Rails, override output for  { :json => @model }

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I like to add a different way json data is rendered in Rails.

*The problem is is that i don't want all the field names for each row, just a array with data for each column, moreover it would be nice to setup some type of filter so you can select which columns you want in the JSON output*

At the moment i have in a controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @person }
end
```

And i would like to do something like:

```
format.json { render :json2 => @person }
```

So that in this specific action of a controller, the JSON data is formatted differently (:json2). I was looking at:

```
ActionController.add_renderer :json2 do |json, options|
```

But i can't wrap my head around this. Were do i start? I do want it to run it in the same way as the 'default' json renderer.  So no separate index.json2.erb files in each view. Even better if i can add some extra fields to the array like:

```
format.json { render :json2 => @person, :table = 'xyz', :columns = ['a', 'b'] }
```

I did read  [Yehuda Katz](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/render-options-in-rails-3/) but i still can't figure it out.

Comment: downvote? for what? i did read the other articles but that was for Rails 2. I just started with Rails 3, and since the differences...

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be great for you to override the to_json method. Here a similar question.

[How to override to_json in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5)