# Return associated models on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Comment` object that can have many `Tag` objects associated with it in a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. On creation I want the comment to include the tags associated to it, hopefully without having to do a separate query. How can this be done?

**EDIT**:

To help clarify my issue, this is my comment creation controller method:

```
def create
  @comment = @current_user.comment!(@post, comment_params[:content])

  render :show, status: :created
end
```

This is my `comment!` method:

```
def comment!(yum, content)
  comment = comments.create!(yum_id: yum.id, content: content)
  comment.create_activity :create, owner: self, recipient: yum.user

  mentions = content.scan(/\@\w+/)
  for mention in mentions
    if mentioned_user = User.find_by_username(mention.sub("@", ""))
      mention!(mentioned_user, comment) 
    end
  end

  comment
end
```

This is the method that checks the text for tags which gets executed before save:

```
def create_tags
  tags = content.scan(/\#[[:alnum:]]+/)
  for tag in tags
    tag = tag.sub("#", "")
    if found_tag = Tag.find_by_content(tag.downcase)
      self.tags << found_tag
    else
      self.tags.build(content: tag)
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my jbuilder view for comments:

```
json.extract! comment, :id, :content, :created_at, :updated_at

json.tags comment.tags do |tag| 
  json.partial! 'api/v1/shared/tag', tag: tag
end

json.user do |json|
  json.partial! 'api/v1/shared/user', user: comment.user
end
```

What I want is the tags to be included when the comment is created (and also the mentions come to think of it, but solving one solves the other). When I'm just displaying comments those are already included, it's on creation that only the comment gets returned.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create the associated tags when you create the comment, i.e. creating the actual database records with the correct `tagID, commentID` rows in the HABTM join table?

Comment: I do create the associated tags when a new comment gets pushed. But I don't do it using accepts_nested_attributes_for since the tags are inside the text itself. I use regex to pull them out and create them alongside the comment, but when I render the show view (json) only the comment gets rendered without the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter Tag objects with a `where` clause:

Replace:

```
  tags = content.scan(/\#[[:alnum:]]+/)
  for tag in tags
    tag = tag.sub("#", "")
    if found_tag = Tag.find_by_content(tag.downcase)
      self.tags << found_tag
    else
      self.tags.build(content: tag)
    end
  end
```

With:

```
  sent_tags = content.scan(/#([[:alnum:]]+)/).flatten.map &:downcase
  self.tags = Tag.where(content: tags) # This is the line that saves multiple queries

  new_tags  = sent_tags - tags.map(&:content)
  new_tags.each do |new_tag|
    self.tags.build(content: new_tag)
  end
```

Note:

```
2.1.2 :016 > "some #Thing #qwe".scan(/#([[:alnum:]]+)/).flatten.map &:downcase
 => ["thing", "qwe"]
```

`sent_tags` will store tags as you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, this can be solved by overriding the `as_json` method of your Comment object.

```
# in Comment.rb

def as_json(options = nil) 
  super( (options || {}).merge({
    include: :tags       
  })
end
```

This should ensure that when the comment is rendered as JSON then the hash also contains the `tags` association. The `as_json` method gets called when you invoke `to_json` on your ActiveRecord object - for a more detailed explanation please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/how-to-override-to-json-in-rails) excellent answer, or the documentation for the `as_json` method for `ActiveModel::Serializers` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json).

Please let me know if I've misunderstood anything about your question! :-)

Comment: No, this is not my problem. My problem is specific to when the comment gets created, not rendered in any case. I'll post some code to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def create
  @comment = @current_user.comment!(@post, comment_params[:content])

  render json: @comment.to_json( include: :tags ), status: :created, location: @comment
end
```