# Using different style for paperclip image in Rails while rendering in json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, paperclip

I have a model which has an image field managed by paperclip:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :default_url => "/images/normal/missing.png",
                :styles => { :medium => "612x612", :small => "300x300" },
                :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

I can access the different sizes like this:

```
    meals.each do |n|
      n.image.url(:small) # gives url for small images
      puts n.image.url # returns url for original images, I want this to return small for this function
    end
```

I am rendering the meals in JSON using `render :json`.

My question is, how can I pass the small image URLs into my meals variable (in my controller below)? I want to be able to return small image URLs as I tried doing above, except return it when my response renders (see below).

UPDATE:

In my controller:

```
def view_patient
  response = Response.new
  this_doctor = Doctor.find_by_remember_token(Doctor.digest(auth_params["remember_token"]))
  if this_doctor
    this_patient = this_doctor.users.find_by_id(params[:id])
      if this_patient
        meals = this_patient.meals
        #
        # Here should be code on how to set the meals.image.url to small
        glucoses = this_patient.glucoses
        response.data = { :patient => this_patient,  :meals => meals }
        response.code = true
      else
        response.error = "Could not find patient"
        response.code = false
      end
  else
    response.error = "Please Login"
    response.code = false
  end
  render :json => response.json
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR

```
# inside meal.rb

def as_json(options=nil)
  super( (options || {}).merge({ 
    :methods => [:small_url]
  }))
end

def small_url
  self.image.url(:small)
end
```

You can then access the URL in your JSON structure

```
JSON.parse(meal.to_json)['small_url']
```

### Explanation

When a ActiveModel is serialized through `to_json` the method `as_json` is first invoked on the object to separate the actual construction of the JSON data structure from the rendering. This data structure (a hash really) is then encoded as a JSON string through `ActiveSupport`.

So in orde to customize the object we wish to display as JSON we need to override the `as_json` method of that object - which is [well documented](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json). As per the documentation, the `methods` key for the options hash simply invokes the methods listed in the array passed as the value (in our case just `small_url`) and creates a key in the hash to be JSON encoded, with the value of the method invocation.

For an even more detailed explanation, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/how-to-override-to-json-in-rails) excellent answer.

Comment: niceeee, sounds like this is exactly what I need. I'm a noob, and the explanation was on point. And nice link to the other question. Will accept when I get a chance to fire this up

Comment: hey @nicohvi , I'm rendering my response with other variables as well, any idea how to store my response with the small urls as opposed to the original? See updated code. Thanks!

Comment: I should think it already does. What do you see when you inspect the `response` JSON object's meals array? I believe the individual meals in that array should all have the attribute `small_url`.

Comment: Thanks you da man, I was missing something in my code, my fault