# Rails Active Record - :includes with only specific fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a simple API.  I'd like this index method to return only two or three fields from the person table, rather than every field from  that table.

```
api :GET, "/v2/branches/", "Return every branch."
  def index
    @branches = Branch.includes(:people, :social_link).where("branches.company_id = ?", @company.id)
    render json: @branches.to_json(include: [:people, :social_link])
  end
```

Rather than returning each persons first born child, i'd just like it to show first_name, last_name, email_address...  Any ideas?

Comment: Is this bigger than what it looks like? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/how-to-override-to-json-in-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, according to [this](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json) blog post, it seems a possible solution is doing this

```
render json: @branches.to_json(
               include: {
                 people: { only: [:first_name, :last_name, :email]},
                 :social_link
               })
```

Although, I would also suggest making a [serializer](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json#ItJIet) for the model if that suits your purpose.