# How to convert a hash to JSON without the converted string being full of backslashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am converting a hash to JSON using `to_json`, but the converted string is full of backslashes. If I use `puts`, it  shows the correct string but if I pass in a `HTTP::NET request.body`, the string is full of backslashes.

```
data = {"a" => "b", "c" => "d", "e" => "f"}
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, {'Content-Type' =>'application/json', 
          'Authorization' => "xyz")
req.body = data.to_json
res = http.request(req)
```

`req.body` is sending:

```
"{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\",\"e\":\"f\"}"
```

My request is failing because of this.

I need to send data as

```
"{"a" => "b", "c" => "d", "e" => "f"}"
```

in the request body.

Comment: This `"{"a" => "b", "c" => "d", "e" => "f"}"` isn't (at least) valid Ruby code. What you see full of backslashes is a perfectly easily parseable JSON representation of your hash.

Comment: i need to send a key value pair without backslashes but in json format. how i will do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to do that. If you send a valid JSON, you receive a valid JSON which you need to parse afterward. If you're not happy with how the json library in Ruby represents your JSON strings, you can build them by yourself (`'{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}' == "{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\",\"e\":\"f\"}"`).

Comment: You are already sending JSON as Sebastian mentioned. Backslashes just used to escape double quotes in a quoted string. If your request is failing it might be caused by another reason. I just tried your code in `irb` it works, my application receives JSON.

Comment: Okay,Thank you all.

Comment: If you examine each character, e.g. `puts req.body[0],req.body[1], req.body[2]` etc you'll see that the third slingle character is in fact "a".  The second single character is in fact `"\""`  The slashes are not really there and not additional characters, they're just ruby's way of displayinhg embedded double_quotes within a string.

Comment: I guess you are not doing JSON.parse at your receiving end?

Comment: @SafwanSM Try `JSON.parse("{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\",\"e\":\"f\"}")` in rails console and you will understand.

Comment: You're confusing the data with the visual representation of the data. `data.to_json # => "{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\",\"e\":\"f\"}"` but `puts data.to_json` outputs `{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}` which is perfect JSON. You can prove this using: `JSON[data] # => "{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\",\"e\":\"f\"}"` then `JSON[JSON[data]] # => {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f"}` which does a complete round-trip of generating then parsing the data and returning the hash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are confused about the actual content of the string. The backslashes are part of the string representation, and are not actually in the string.

Take for example `'"'` a single character `"`. When you enter this into irb the output will be:

```
s = '"'
#=> "\""
```

From the result `"\""` the starting `"` and ending `"` mark the begin and ending of the string while `\"` is an escaped double quote, and represents a single `"`. The reason this double quote is escaped is because you want Ruby to interpret it as an `"` character, not as the end of the string.

You can view the actual contents of the string without escape characters by printing it to the console.

```
puts s
# "
#=> nil
```

Here you can see that there is no backslash in the contents of the string.

---

The same applies for your `to_json` call, which returns a string:

```
data = {"a" => "b", "c" => "d", "e" => "f"}
json = data.to_json
#=> "{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\",\"e\":\"f\"}"
puts json
# {"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}
#=> nil
```

Like you can see there are no backslashes in the contents of the string, only in the string representation.

Comment: I think this is the real problem and solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle this problem with two solutions: Either you can parse the JSON where you want to use it, or you can also send parsed JSON from Ruby code.

```
req.body = JSON.parse(data.to_json)
```

It will return the result like:

```
{"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f"}
```

It depends on you where you want to parse your data. If you want to parse on the frontend just use jQuery's JSON parse function.

Comment: `JSON.parse(data.to_json)` will convert json to hash again.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Grammar is very important on SO. Please take the time to use proper punctuation and capitalization. SO isn't a message board or forum, it's more like an online reference book.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`as_json`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) which might be more appropriate given what you're attempting. This is [a good explanation of which to use and when](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2574900/721065). `as_json` will produce unescaped json.

Answer (score -1):

Totally understand that the slash is an accepted escape on the string, but there are applications that do not accept it IE Amazon Connect.

req.body = JSON.parse(data.to_json)

Works perfectly.