# restrict backslash while convering to JSON from ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a ruby API's.This API fetching db value and converted into a JSON format.

This is the table data
[image]

Below code used to fetch data from db and converted into JSON format

```
def get_data
       
        response= data.select(:xx, :xxx, :xxx, :xxx ).where(:id => xxx1,:xx1 => xx1)
        if response.empty?
            respond_to do |format|
                msg = {:message => "No records found"}
                format.json { render :json => msg }
            end
        else
            respond_to do |format|
                format.json { render json: response.to_json }
            end
        end
    end
```

Now am getting the response like below

[image]

How can i remove the slash from the response?
Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I was tested this API's from `POSTMAN`

Executed following solutions but the result was same

1. use `as_json` instead of `to_json`
2. removed `.to_json`

Comment: try changing to_json to as_json

Comment: @andylee i was tested as_json instead fo to_json getting same response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926393/how-to-convert-a-hash-to-json-without-the-converted-string-being-full-of-backsla  check this answer.  as_json should not be adding backslashes to the result, so it seems that backslash is added before converting to json. 
 By the way, backslash is usually ok for most of the clients as many client platform can handle escaped strings.  Test on your real client  instead of postman

Comment: yes you could try testing in you real client or try with something like `response = JSON.parse(data.select(:xx, :xxx, :xxx, :xxx ).where(:id => xxx1,:xx1 => xx1))`

Comment: The value of `data1` looks like a valid string representation of a JSON hash. JSON parsing that string should return a valid hash. What do you expect the value to look like instead? Do you want to encode the string differently? Do you want to return a hash instead?

Comment: what is the type of your db column?

Comment: @spickermann expected out put should be [
  {
   "id": 257,
   "data1": "{"tbl_name":"tbl1","tbl_name":"tbl2","tbl_name":"tbl3"}"
  }
 ]

Comment: @NathanGouy it is varchar

Comment: Did you consider using a [`jsonb` column type](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb) in the database to store our hash structure, instead of serializing it to a `varchar`?

Comment: that's why then

If it's a string, it will be serialize as a string (even if the whole object is serialized as json, the actual value of your specific key will be a string)

You could or have a jsonb column instead, or having a serializer (builder, activerecord serializer, panko ...) and do "type casting" when you serialize

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the variable `response` in a controller action.

It is already used by Rails: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object